# Can Shias pray at a Sunni mosque?

Tags: salat, sunnah, shiism, masjid

Regarding using a Sunni mosque as a Shia:

1- Can the aasna ashariah (the 12-imam Shias) use a Sunni mosque and pray alongside their Sunni brothers and Sisters?

2- Are they expected to fully observe the Sunni tradition of praying (i.e. crossing arms, closing prayer by saying salam shoulder to shoulder, letting the imam say most zikrs in jama'ah) or can they observe the Shia code of prayer in jamaa'ah?

3- Are they expected to fully observe the Sunni tradition of praying in furadah?

4- Scholarly opinion aside, how are Shias in a mosque perceived by Sunnis?

Comment: Number 4 is another question, maybe you should ask it separately. Also, please make it clear that you want a "Sunni view on Shia praying in Sunni mosques".

Answer (score 3):

From a sunni point of view:

> 1- Can the aasna ashariah (the 12-imam Shias) use a Sunni mosque and
>   pray alongside their Sunni brothers and Sisters?

I have seen many shia's pray in suni masjid. Some even use that little clay stone they get from Karbala. No one would bother them.

> 2- Are they expected to fully observe the Sunni tradition of praying
>   (i.e. crossing arms, closing prayer by saying salam shoulder to
>   shoulder, letting the imam say most zikrs in jama'ah) or can they
>   observe the Shia code of prayer in jamaa'ah?

No. Many sunni amongst themselves don't - ex: some have their hands down some crossed, they won't expect it unless it is too disruptive to the other prayers.

> 3- Are they expected to fully observe the Sunni tradition of praying
>   in furadah?

Same as above, no.

> 4- Scholarly opinion aside, how are Shias in a mosque perceived by
>   Sunnis?

They might get a look or two, maybe people will chat about how weird they are praying. People always tend to talk when actions get out of the norm.

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects to the matter which are mixed and affect each other.

1. What your Marja' says in this regard...yet most the general idea is that Sunni and Shias, pray to the same God, Ka'ba and almost in the same way and at almost at the same time, use the same Suras and say the same words!
2. Relative to what your Marja' says the social aspects which you have to make the decision... I mean if Sunni brothers and sisters are welcoming to where you go then why not? I actually think it's good to show that whatever our differences are we should show stick to what keeps us closer!

Comment: I wish you gave at least an example from a scholar or Marja' as a presented source, afterward your good answer would be great in spite of a short content.

Answer (score -2):

Sunni and Shia are all Muslim only have very subtle differences and nothing important to outline out unnecessarily unless you are a münafıks or a Kufr wanting to sow hatred amongst Muslims.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. This looks more likely like a comment and does nothing to answer the actual question and is therefore posted in the wrong section.

Answer (score -3):

Yes they can pray in any mosque i prayed along with shias in a sunni mosque.if there's a jammaa They can pray in a part of a mosque in there way where its away from sunni praying so they dont ruin the jamaa for sunnis.thats the answer of your question in islam. but when you look at how some racist people might react depending on the region you cant do that anywhere.

Comment: uh-huh, I really appreciate what you mentioned without bias. Of course your answer could be more complete by referring to ahadith or even Sunni or Shia scholars as well, but on the whole you mentioned a fair issue. Good luck mate.